# Why can't I separate in the Object Mode

Tags: tools

[image]
As the video did, the vlogger separated the door into parts, and I want to separate the desk which I joined before as he did, but I can't find the separate tool in object mode, it only appears in mesh/separate in edit mode, why? And if I want to unjoin the desk into parts like before, how can I do it? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The author of the video gives the answer in the comments, it's not available anymore in *Object* mode in the latest versions, so you need to switch to *Edit* mode.

Comment: Well, but it's true - this was possible in earlier versions. It's actually a pity this does not work anymore.

Comment: Oh OK I'm going to correct then

Comment: Of course it's unfortunate that the video is labeled "compatible with 3.6" and there are many things that do not anymore work like it's shown there (that's not the only thing), and especially when it's "absolute basics" and aimed at beginners... because they will have a hard time figuring that out. Someone like me watches tutorials on TV for example and there I cannot read comments and find out what he explains there. But well, that's none of my business and not relevant here on BSE. We are just giving first aid to those who struggle with these tutorials :)